# Can't read or upload a file name in php after moving to web server

Tags: php

I'm trying to upload a file with php and the code i created worked fine in my localhost on my machine, however, after uploading to a web server, it sees the filename on the form as empty and does not even read it.
This is the code i created. It reads the uploaded filename as blank. Please help.

```
<form action="registerSchool.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1">

                <input type="text" name="schoolName" id="name" placeholder="Name of School" />

                <input type="text" name="schoolAddr" id="Address" placeholder="School Address" />

                <input type="text" name="schooluri" id="uri" placeholder="School Home Page URL" />

                <label for="logo">Upload School logo: </label><input name="logo" type="file" id="logo" />

                <input type="text" name="superAdminUser" id="Admin_username" placeholder="Super Admin UserName" />

                <input type="password" name="superAdminPass" id="Admin_Password" placeholder="Super Admin Password" />

                <input type="password" name="superAdminPass2" placeholder="Enter Password Again" />

                <input type="submit" name="Submit" class="button button-small align_right" value="Create Institution" /><td>

    </form>

<?php
session_start();
// create short variable names
$schoolName = $_POST['schoolName'];
$schoolAddr = $_POST['schoolAddr'];
$schooluri = $_POST['schooluri'];
$superAdminUser = $_POST['superAdminUser'];
$superAdminPass = $_POST['superAdminPass'];
$superAdminPass2 = $_POST['superAdminPass2'];

$logo = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['logo']['name']);

//This is the directory where images will be saved
$target = "resources/";
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['logo']['name']);

//check if the fields are filled
if(empty($schoolName) || empty($schoolAddr) || empty($superAdminUser) || empty($superAdminPass) || empty($superAdminPass2) || empty($schooluri))
{
    //redirect
    header('Location: RegisterNewSchool.php?failure=1'); 
    die;
}

if(empty($logo))
{
    //redirect
    header('Location: RegisterNewSchool.php?failure4=1'); 
    die;
}

//check if admin passwords match
if($superAdminPass != $superAdminPass2)
{
    //redirect
    header('Location: RegisterNewSchool.php?failure1=1'); 
    die;
}

if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
    $schoolName = mysql_real_escape_string($schoolName);
    $schoolAddr = mysql_real_escape_string($schoolAddr);
    $schooluri = mysql_real_escape_string($schooluri);
    $superAdminUser = mysql_real_escape_string($superAdminUser);
    $superAdminPass = mysql_real_escape_string($superAdminPass);
    $superAdminPass2 = mysql_real_escape_string($superAdminPass2);
}


//verify if logo is cool
if($_FILES["logo"]["size"] < 500000) {
    //verify if logo has uploaded to server
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['logo']['tmp_name'], $target)){            
        //connect to the database
        include('dbconnect.php');

        //query the database
        $query5 = "CREATE TABLE studentDetails
                    ( student_id int(11) not null auto_increment primary key,
                    registration_number char(50) not null,
                    surname char(200),
                    othernames char(200),
                    student_pass char(50)
                    )";
        $query = "CREATE TABLE schoolDetails
                    ( school_id int(11) not null auto_increment primary key,
                    school_name char(50) not null,
                    school_addr char(200),
                    schooluri char(150),
                    school_logo varchar(50)
                    )";
        $query2 = "CREATE TABLE adminDetails( admin_id int(11) not null auto_increment primary key,
                    admin_type char(20) not null,
                    admin_name char(50),
                    admin_pass char(50)
                    )";
        $query3 = "INSERT INTO schoolDetails(school_name,school_addr,schooluri,school_logo)
                VALUES('".$schoolName."','".$schoolAddr."','".$schooluri."','".$logo."')";
        $query4 = "INSERT INTO adminDetails(admin_type,admin_name,admin_pass)
                VALUES('super','".$superAdminUser."','".$superAdminPass."')";

        $result = $db->query($query);
        $result2 = $db->query($query2);
        $result3 = $db->query($query3);
        $result4 = $db->query($query4);
        $result5 = $db->query($query5);
        if ($result5) {
            echo 'query success';
        } else {
            echo 'An error occurred. '. mysqli_error($db);
        }

        //disconnect from the database
        include('dbdisconnect.php');
        //redirect
        $_SESSION['valid_admin'] = $superAdminUser;
        header('Location: AdminPanel.php?success=1'); 
        die;

    }
    else {
        //redirect
        header('Location: RegisterNewSchool.php?failure2=1'); 
        die;
    }
}
else {
        //redirect
        header('Location: RegisterNewSchool.php?failure3=1'); 
        die;
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the rights to write on the server ? May be you just need to chmod the folder

your code should work I think

Comment: try chmod -R 777 <directory_name> in your console. But be carefull with security. Use this command only for the upload directory.

Comment: Thanks, the default permission on the directory is 755, on changing is to 777, it returns 'page not found' in my web browser

Comment: i dont understand when are you getting this message ? when you upload the file ?

Comment: Please note, the script above is redirecting at the if(empty($logo))
{
    //redirect
    header('Location: RegisterNewSchool.php?failure4=1'); 
    die;
}

Comment: Its not attempting to upload at all, it is returning a null file name whenever i try to upload, behaving as i didn't select an upload file.

Comment: It is two separate files, the first(RegisterNewSchool.php) holds the form, and the second(registerSchool.php) redirects back to the first after trying to process the form

Comment: try `if (!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['logo']['tmp_name'])` instead of `if(empty($logo))` to check

Comment: Tried as you stated above, but still behaves the way it has been. Here is a link to the site: http://goodcreation.com.ng/divineportal

Comment: It worked fine on my local machine but is behaving this way when i upload to the web server.